# While reading the data from database problem

Tags: c#, database

I have rectified my previous problem and now able to insert data to the table.
Now while reading the data with Name, Age, Gender,City, TypeofDisease condition not getting the result..as a result always I'm getting "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader"
Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchPatient
(
@Name varchar(50),
@Age int,
@Gender varchar(50),
@City varchar(50),
@TypeofDisease varchar(50)
)
 AS
select * from Patient where Name=@Name and Age=@Age and Gender=@Gender and City=@City and TypeofDisease=@TypeofDisease
GO
```

And here is my event code:

```
protected void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        string name = TxtName.Text.Trim();
        int age = Convert.ToInt32(TxtAge.Text);
        string gender;
        if (RadioButtonMale.Checked)
        {
            gender = RadioButtonMale.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            gender = RadioButtonFemale.Text;
        }
        string city = DropDownListCity.SelectedItem.Value;

        string typeofdisease = "";
        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxListDisease.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                typeofdisease += li.Value;
            }
        }
        string[] sl=typeofdisease.Split();
        foreach (string s in sl)
        {
            ListItem itm = CheckBoxListDisease.Items.FindByValue(s);
            if (itm != null)
            {
                itm.Selected = true;
            }
        }
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SearchPatient", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            com.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name;
            com.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int).Value = age;
            com.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = gender;
            com.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = city;
            com.Parameters.Add("@TypeofDisease", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = sl.ToString();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(dr);
            lblPatientDetails.Text = sb.ToString();          
        }
        catch
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            com.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Pls somebody modify my code, to achieve my expected result..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use methods from dr, the [**SqlDataReader**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_members.aspx).  For example

- dr.GetValue()   (To get a given column from the current row)
- dr.GetValues()  (To get all values from current row)
- dr.NextResult()   (to get to the next row of data in the resultset)

The reason why you keep getting "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader" instead of some result is that assigning dr to a string (by way of StringBuilder.Append) uses, implicitly, the ToString() method of this object which produces this particular string (a useful debug feature, but otherwise not very applicable one).

Answer (score 0):

```
 dr = com.ExecuteReader();
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append(dr);
 lblPatientDetails.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Change to :

```
using(SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader())
{
     if(rdr.HasRows)
     {
       while(rdr.Read())
       {
        sb.Append(rdr.GetString(0)); 
        ..... etc
       }
     }
}
```

Or You can create DataSet.

```
    using (SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
        return dataSet;
    }
```